# How to generate reports from Form Library documents?

Tags: 2010, infopath, form, reports

I'm fairly new to SharePoint 2010 and have no formal coding experience, so bear with me.

I just created and uploaded an InfoPath form to a Form Library in SharePoint 2010. The form works well. However, I want to know how to query and export the data that's in those forms into Excel so I can then work with that data.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No code needed. You could create a data connection to the file in the form library using Excel's Get External Data method and map the XML contents that comprise the file to Excel.

In Excel, on the Data tab, in the Get External Data group, click From Other Sources. Choose From XML Data Import. In the Select Data Import dialog box, navigate to the form library on your SharePoint site. It should resemble this format (both https):

In 2013: //[your domain].sharepoint.com/[site]/[form library]

In 2010: //sharepoint.[your domain].com/[site]/[form library]

(If this doesn't work, you'll need to get the webDAV address to your SharePoint library by either [mapping a network drive](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/?id=1603) or by using the Open with Explorer feature in the Library tab of the Ribbon in your form library and get the address from there.)

Click OK. In the Import Data dialog box, select XML table in existing worksheet, select a range in Excel, click OK. (You should also check the XML map properties before clicking OK and make sure that the Save data source definition in workbook checkbox is checked.)

The InfoPath data is now mapped to your Excel workbook and you can refresh the data as needed.

Comment: Hi Tony! Thanks for responding. I wasn't aware of this method. However, I did figure out how to promote fields and then export data into Excel from SharePoint (which sounds like the reverse of what suggested). Anyway, thanks for showing me another solution (and one that could provide more flexibility in terms of how data appears once it's opened in Excel)!